# (node:13612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: user is not defined

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to login using the id from mongoDB but nodejs keeps giving me this error about user...

(node:13612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: user is not defined

registering the user is alright but when calling the login ..... it crashs although everything is defined and I can't figure out why its not reading user from the database

...

```
const express = require("express");
const { findOne } = require("../models/User");

const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const { registerValidation, loginValidation } = require("../validation");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  //VALIDATE DATA
  const { error } = registerValidation(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  //CHECK IF USER EXISTS
  const emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (emailExist) return res.status(400).send("Email already exists!");
  //HASH THE PASSWORD
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
  //CREATE NEW USER
  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashPassword,
  });
  try {
    const savedUser = await user.save();
    res.send({user:user._id});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  //VALIDATE DATA
  const { error } = loginValidation(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  //CHECK IF USER EXISTS
  const emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (!emailExist) return res.status(400).send("Email or Password is Wrong");

  //CREATE AND ASSIGN TOKEN
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);

  res.header("auth-token", token).send(token);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is an undefined variable:

```js
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
```

The `user` (user._id) variable in the line above isn't defined in the Login route, perhaps you meant to find the user first, then to assign the JWT Token?

Comment: yes exactly, i want to assign the user when logging in a token

Comment: Then simply use `let user = await User.find({...})` and use that user's id in your code